# Node socket.write returns more bytes written than in the original buffer

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I am using a node function to compile a buffer that is made up of a header and payload.  The first term in the header is the total size of the buffer that is being sent to the server, the second element is the command that is being sent to the server and then the payload is added to the buffer.  using the bufferpack.js library from NPM when I calculate the length of the required buffer I am getting the same size as after the buffer has been created and I get back the length property of the buffer.

The issue I am seeing is that once the buffer is more than 127 bytes the number of bytes written does not match the number of bytes in the actual buffer, in the testing I have done its 2 bytes longer.  This is causing an issue on the server as it doesn't know what to do with the extra bytes.

Here is the method that I am using to convert the data to a buffer and then send the buffer to the server

```
_sendall(cmd, payload='', callback){
  console.log('payload:', payload.length)
  let fmt = '>HB'
  let size = struct.calcLength(fmt) + payload.length
  console.log('size:',size)
  let header = [size, cmd]
  let buf = struct.pack(fmt, header) + payload
  console.log('buf:', buf.length)
  console.log('[INFO] Buffer Sent:',buf)
  this.sock.write(buf, 'binary', (err)=>{
    console.log('[INFO] Bytes written now:', this.sock.bytesWritten-this._bytesWrittenPrevious)
    console.log('[INFO] Total Bytes Written:', this.sock.bytesWritten)
    this._bytesWrittenPrevious = this.sock.bytesWritten
    if (err) {
      console.log('[ERROR] _sendall:', err)
      return callback(false)
    }
    return callback(true)
  })
}
```

Here is an example of the console output when the system works correctly and the bytes sent match the size of the buffer.  The server responds and all is right in the world.

```
[INFO] Sending the input setup 
payload: 20 
size: 23 
buf: 23 
[INFO] Buffer Sent: Iinput_int_register_0 
[INFO] Bytes written now: 23 
[INFO] Total Bytes Written: 143
```

Here is what I am seeing when the system is not working correctly and the server never responds back and the code hangs up as there are callbacks that never fire.

```
[INFO] Sending the input setup
payload: 143
size: 146
buf: 146
[INFO] Buffer Sent: �Iinput_double_register_0,input_double_register_1,input_double_register_2,input_double_register_3,input_double_register_4,input_double_register_5
[INFO] Bytes written now: 148
[INFO] Total Bytes Written: 291
```

Any ideas what is happening?  I have not been able to find anything regarding an issue such as this so any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I made the changes recommended by @mscdex to the encoding in the sock.write and now I am writing the same number of bytes that I am sending but I am still having an issue.  I have narrowed it down to the size element which is being encoded as an unsigned short (H) using the bufferpack.js library.  Anytime size is more than 127 I believe its encoding it incorrectly, if I try to unpack the buffer I am getting a NaN return value for the size.  Still working on resolving the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you're sending binary data, you do not want to be specifying `'utf8'` as the encoding. You really should be using [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html) objects instead of strings for binary data. However, to write a binary string, you can use the `'binary'` encoding instead. That will keep the string from being interpreted as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, that made the size of the bytes written now match the size of the buffer that was built.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make the program work by ditching the bufferpack.js library for packing the buffer.  It appears that it was not encoding the size of the buffer that was being sent correctly anytime the size of the buffer exceeds 127 bytes.  The `H` in the `fmt` variable was supposed to format the byte as an unsigned short, appears to be looking for a signed short but that is just conjecture at this time until I have time to dig into it further as I got the same result using `h` which is a signed short.

To solve the issue I switched to using the native buffer write methods and this has solved the issue.  I will look into the bufferpack.js and see if I can find the issue and post a PR to the repo if I'm able to correct it.

Here is the new code that works as expected:

```
_sendall(cmd, payload='', callback){
  let fmt = '>HB'
  let size = struct.calcLength(fmt) + payload.length
  let header = [size, cmd]
  let buf = new Buffer(size)
  buf.writeUInt16BE(size, 0)
  buf.writeInt8(cmd, 2)
  buf.write(payload.toString(), 3)
  this.sock.write(buf, 'binary', (err)=>{
    console.log('[INFO] Bytes written now:', this.sock.bytesWritten-this._bytesWrittenPrevious)
    console.log('[INFO] Total Bytes Written:', this.sock.bytesWritten)
    this._bytesWrittenPrevious = this.sock.bytesWritten
    if (err) {
      console.log('[ERROR] _sendall:', err)
      return callback(false)
    }
    return callback(true)
  })
}
```

Comment: If you're using Buffers, you don't need the `'binary'` argument at all (that's only for strings), just: `write(buf, (err) => { ... })`